Using (including) pcapplusplus in .pro qmake
This is my pro file to build simple project in QT6 with pcapplusplus
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17


# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

INCLUDEPATH += C:/Users\kostr/Documents/TestDiploma/libs/pcap-builded/include/pcapplusplus
LIBS += -LC:/Users/kostr/Documents/TestDiploma/libs/pcap-builded/lib -llibPcap++ -llibPacket++ -llibCommon++
CONFIG += static

This is my mainwindow.cpp file:
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "PcapLiveDeviceList.h"
#include "Packet.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    pcpp::PcapLiveDevice* dev = pcpp::PcapLiveDeviceList::getInstance().getPcapLiveDeviceByIp("192.168.1.1");

        if (dev != nullptr) {
            std::cout << "No device: " << dev->getName() << std::endl;
        }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

If I start building my output is fulfilled with udefined reference to ''. In count of 103. Qt6, MinGW, qmake
My pcap++ tree is:
project_path/libs/pcap-builded
                          include/pcapplusplus/<*.h>
                          bin/<*.exe>
                          lib
                              cmake/pcapplusplus/<*.cmake>
                              libCommon++.a
                              libPacket++.a
                              libPcap++.a

